# How to check if PSFTP process returns 0 with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, putty, return-code

I am writing a batch script with takes files from a directory and copies them remotely using psftp.

Here is the line that does all the magic:

```
echo n | psftp.exe user@hostname.com -i id_rsa.ppk -v -b psftp-rules.txt -bc >> c:\log-file.txt
```

As you can see, the `psftp.exe` is called and the authenticated via a rsa key. The putting takes place in the `psftp-rules.txt` and the activity is recorded in the `log-file.txt`.

What I need is a function that will check for a return code, and if there is any failure, to write the error to the log file and then quit.

What I am looking for is perhaps setting a variable for this return code. Then I imagine an if statement that is the variable equals 1 to end the script and echo an error message into a log.

The issue I am seeing is that once the line above is ran, the batch script if not involved. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Check if psftp sets an error code

Check the value of `%ErrorLevel%` right after the function has run.  Run this in both a successful workflow and failure workflow to verify that the ErrorLevel was set upon failure.

```
echo %ErrorLevel%
echo n | psftp.exe user@hostname.com -i id_rsa.ppk -v -b psftp-rules.txt -bc >> c:\log-file.txt
echo %ErrorLevel%
```

#### Update

Store the ErrorLevel in a variable and evaluate

```
echo n | ...
set "ExitCode=%ErrorLevel%"
if "%ExitCode%"=="1" echo This is my error message for error 1 > c:\log-file.txt & exit /b %ExitCode%
```

If you want to capture all positive ErrorLevels and echo the same message use the following if statement.

```
echo n | ...
if ErrorLevel 1 echo This is my error message for error 1+ > c:\log-file.txt & exit /b %ErrorLevel%
```

Comment: Thank you David. I was wondering what would I need to do if I wanted to make the return code for the above function a variable? Ideally I also want to make an if statement for the variable. If the variable for example = 1 (an error) to quit the script and echo a message into a log. I'm a Linux guy, so forgive the question. Thanks!

Comment: @NerdyBird  Sorry, I missed your questions till now.  Updated answer with examples.

Comment: Be careful using ErrorLevel as an environment variable. See https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx?Redirected=true